# single quotes not working in shell script

Tags: unix, bash

I have a .bash_profile script and I can't get the following to work 
alias lsls='ls -l | sort -n +4'

when I type the alias lsls 
it does the sort but then posts this error message 
"-bash: +4: command not found"
How do I get the alias to work with '+4'?

It works when type  ls -l | sort -n +4  in the command line

I'm in OS X 10.4

Thanks for any help

Comment: The original set of tags, "vi", "single", "quotes", must be the least adapted to the question I have ever seen on this site. And there are indeed weird tags on this site.

Answer (score 3):

```
bash-4.0$ ls -l | sort -n +4
sort: open failed: +4: No such file or directory
```

You need `ls -l | sort -n -k 5`, gnu sort is different from bsd sort

```
alias lsls='ls -l | sort -n -k 5'
```

Edit: updated to reflect change from 0 based indexing to 1 based indexing, thanks Matthew.

Comment: That's not the "+4: command not found" error that was being reported.  The `sort` in OS X 10.4 supports both syntaxes.  And the equivalent of `+4` would be `-k 5`.

Comment: @Matthew And you are right, seems +4 is supported in OS X 10.4, the alias worked perfectly for me on OS X 10.4.

Answer (score 1):

`alias lsls='ls -l | sort -n +4'` should work fine with the `sort` in OS X 10.4 (which *does* support that syntax).

> when I type the alias lsls it does the sort but then posts this error message "-bash: +4: command not found"

Is it possible that you inserted a stray newline when editing your .bash_profile?  e.g. if you ended up with something like this:

```
alias lsls='ls -l | sort -n
+4'
```

...that might explain the error message.

---

As an aside, you can get the same effect without piping through `sort` at all, using:

```
ls -lrS
```

Comment: ls -lrS is a better answer, but sort -n +4 doesn't work on OSX 10.6.x at least

Comment: Right, but the original poster did specifically say "I'm in OS X 10.4".  And I actually tried it.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=32176) link discusses a very similar alias containing a pipe.

The problem may not have been the pipe, but the *interesting* solution was to use a function.

Comment: The issue is not the pipe, the issue is that gnu sort takes different arguments; the +4 should be -k 4